# How do I change the concurrency levels in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I try to:

```
set wlm_query_slot_count to 10;
```

I get an error msg, "...query cannot run because wlm_query_slot_count is greater than the query concurrency for the queue, ... increase the query concurrency if you need more slots"

I've searched and searched, but cannot figure out where I can change the concurrency level (I'd like to raise it from its current 5 to 10).

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer in AWS docs, under parameter groups

[Change concurrency setting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-parameter-groups-console.html#parameter-group-modify)